# powershell script - different behavior after start with windows scheduler

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have this script to check if there is mapped disk on remote server. When I run it in command line, it works perfectly, from PowerGUI and ISE it works perfectly, but when I shedule it in Windows task scheduler, I get a mail message (mail sending part of script is not included), that disk is not mapped - the "else" is executed in spite of disk is mapped.

```
if(Invoke-Command -ComputerName sdebt -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName sdebt -Filter "DeviceID = 'L:'"}) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "L: is OK"} else {
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta "L: is NOT OK" 
                $subject = "CHYBA: Disk L is not mapped"
                $body += "Disk L is not mapped `r" }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Probably is related with permissions.**

- When you run it from your commandline/ISE/PowerGUI you are using your credentials
- When you run it from schedule task by default you run it with system credentials

If I were you I would:

1. Try running it with your credentials to see if this make a difference.
2. Try running it with highest privileges

If after 1) and 2) still fails at least you know for sure that is not a permission issue :-)

Comment: Of course. I think that at some point of creating the script I was thinking about the different credentials defined in Task scheduler, but then I forgot it:( Sorry for stupid question and thank you!

Comment: It was a valid question... I am happy I helped you :)